# Vscode (version: 1.46.1) not indexing all files for search (after update)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Noticed that after an upgrade (of vscode), i see this clock icon on the search bar. Basically searching across codebase is not working. It seems to be stuck at trying to index the codebase. Anyone faced similar issue? I',m on Version: 1.46.1.

[image: vscode not indexing files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing similar issue, downgrading to Version: 1.43.2 worked for me.

Comment: Windows XP was the last Windows OS with decent search in Explorer. Nowadays it's just pointless to use and the greatest alternative I found is [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/). Now VS Code is from Microsoft as well, so perhaps they're going down the same path. File indexing is really poor in more complex projects. I have to open literally every file (which I can close after a second), so the "Find in folder" option works as intended. Hoping for an "Everything" extension...